# How do I focus on a javascript radio button or any other items on specific jquery tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript validation that validates items such as textboxes, radio buttons etc. How do I use focus() on the text box or other item located in a specific tab governed by  tags?

Sample of the javascript code:

```
if (theForm.radbtnProg.checked && theForm.ddlProg.selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert("Please select Institution Name from the list.");
    theForm.ddlProg.focus();
}
```

Above example theForm.radbtnProg.checked and theForm.ddlProg.selectedIndex are the radio button and drop down list that I want to validate. How do I refer to them according to specific tabs?

```
$('#tabs').tabs(theForm.radbtnProg.checked)?
```

**Edited:**
Answered by @nnnnnn and I modified the code:

```
if (theForm.radProg.checked && theForm.ddlProg.selectedIndex == 0) {
    alert("Please select Program Name from the list.");
    $('#tabs').tabs("select", 0);
    $("#ddlProg").focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can't focus on invisible elements. You need to make the appropriate tab active first (making your element visisble) and then focus.

Comment: Done! Thanks @nnnnnn! Problem was i didn't navigate to the active tab before doing the focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select what you want to focus, and call jQuery's [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

```
$(theForm.ddlProg).focus();
```

And of course you could select this `select` any other way:

```
$("select[name='ddlProg']").focus();
```

Comment: Hi @Adam, can you state a code example on what I should select? From above example, ddlProg drop down list is in the first tab and the system can't focus on it and gives an error:

Comment: The code I put in the answer should select it.  Does it not work?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried it and doesn't work. Can't seem to navigate to the ddl. ddlProg is in the first tab (tab1) while my submit button is in the forth tab.

Comment: Can you give ddlProg an id?  If so, use `$("#ddlProdsId").focus();`

Comment: ddlProg is the ID that I set it to. Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: @WenJi Maybe a dropdown can't be selected?  I'm not sure.  Try this, `alert($("#ddlProg).val());` that should at least alert the select's current value.  If that workds, but the same selector with focus doesn't then I'm not sure

Comment: @WenJi - also, do you see any errors in the chrome/firebug console?

Comment: Hey @Adam, problem was solved thanks a lot. The error that displayed was "Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.". Apparently I need to direct it to active tab first before I could focus on it.